# I have an final year project based on Web based in C# ASP.net when i run it, it will show the error

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
Protected void Page_PreInit(object sender,Event args e)
{
this.Theme=Session["Theme name"].ToString();
}
```

> null exception error was unhandle by
>   user code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the value of:

```
Session["Theme name"]
```

is NULL.

You should test this before the line. Something like:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender,Event args e) 
{ 
if(Session["Theme name"] != null)
{
this.Theme=Session["Theme name"].ToString(); 
}
else
{
//use the default theme
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check this

[c# how to set up and use session state from preinit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342970/c-how-to-set-up-and-use-session-state-from-preinit)

Answer (score 0):

i think your session "Session["Theme name"]" not contains any theme name. i think your session is returning null so before setting value to page.theme first check for existence of value in session