# Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am little bit confused... I have the following in my web.config and i am still getting error message. This error only happens when i am logged in since the user info is in the session. In not logged in mode, i just get empty user.

Error:

```
Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, 
either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also
make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state
module is included in the <configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules> 
section in the application configuration.
```

Web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" sqlConnectionString="data source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;user id=user;password=password" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: What event are you attempting to call the session in? Please post the code you're using to access the session that is throwing the exception.

Comment: var user = Session[SessionConstants.LoggedInUser] as SiteUSer;

Comment: You can't call the session so easily from PreInit. See

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342970/c-sharp-how-to-set-up-and-use-session-state-from-preinit

Comment: Are you certain the root exception is being thrown at that line? I've gotten that exact message before when an exception was thrown in Global.asax or a PreInit and and my error handler then tried to access session.

Comment: Yes. We are here working with Kentico CMS and i am going to contact them for more information.