# MVC session expiring but not authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, session-timeout

I'm developing a C# MVC application and I can't seem to get the Authentication and Session timeouts to synchronize. I have a basic Forms Authentication setup and some limited session values. I set the Authentication timeout less than the session (28 minutes vs 30) but running against the development web server, the session will be wiped on a restart of the server but the authentication sticks around. I'm assuming that the authentication is being stored in a cookie that obviously survives the server restart.

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="28" />
</authentication>
<sessionState timeout="30" />
```

I think I want to force the the authentication to timeout if Session is null, to then force a login.

Is that what I actually want to do? If so how and where do I do this?

If not, what is the proper way to handle this?

**EDIT**

For more of a perspective I also posted this question for this same project: [Login as... best practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281191/login-as-best-practices)

Comment: You can store session in SQL server, that way the session will persist.

Comment: A better approach would be to write your app in a session agnostic way, and not depend on session to the degree that it makes a difference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found my answer. Override the Authorize attribute. This seems like the most elegant approach:

```
public class AuthorizeWithSessionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Session == null || httpContext.Session["CurrentUser"] == null)
            return false;

        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could handle this in global.asax with PreRequestHandlerExecute event handler

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Check if user is authenticated
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            if (!authTicket.Expired)
            {
                if (Session["XYZ"] == null)
                {
                    //Session is null, redirect to login page
                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                    Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl, true);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Or, you could write a Httpmodule and implement `context_AuthenticateRequest` to check if session exists and handle the request accordingly.

Hope that helps.

**Edit by Valamas**

See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1446575/511438 for help with the session error.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. Thanks! I will let you know if it actually solves my problem.

Comment: Nope, no dice. "Session state is not available in this context."

Comment: I will try a Httpmodule later and let you know

Comment: Session is not always loaded for content pages such as image files, CSS, js etc. You probably want to implement IRequiresSessionState in HTTPModule. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375627/irequiressessionstate-how-do-i-use-it