# Access session in IHttpModule and being able to do a response.redirect

Tags: asp.net, ihttpmodule

Following the solution found at [Can I access session state from an HTTPModule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276355/can-i-access-session-state-from-an-httpmodule), I am able to access the session state from an IHttpModule.  I'm using it to control access to some files, so in the event someone doesn't have access, I would like to redirect them to a login page.  When I try to do a HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(page); it locks the web server up.  So my post acquire request state function looks like this...

```
 void Application_PostAcquireRequestState(object source, EventArgs e)
    {            
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;

        MyHttpHandler resourceHttpHandler = HttpContext.Current.Handler as MyHttpHandler;

        if (resourceHttpHandler != null)
        {
            // set the original handler back
            HttpContext.Current.Handler = resourceHttpHandler.OriginalHandler;
        }

        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        string filePath = context.Request.FilePath;
        context.Trace.Write("HttpDownloadModule", "File path: " + filePath);

        Boolean hasAccess = true;

        if (filePath.Contains("content/downloads"))
        {
            //check to make sure a session has been established already....
            if (context.Session == null)
                hasAccess = false;

            SecurityBLL security = new SecurityBLL();
            string fileName = filePath.Split('/').Last();

            //check to see if a user is logged in
            if (!CitrixAccess.loggedin)
                hasAccess = false;

            //check access for download
            if (!security.checkSecurityByDownload(fileName))
                hasAccess = false;

            if (!hasAccess)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Handler = resourceHttpHandler.OriginalHandler;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("../../login.aspx");
            }
        }

    }
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found a workaround...  I moved my hasAccess variable to be global and added an EndRequest handler.  So I'm checking for hasAccess in EndRequest and doing the redirect from there.

Answer (score 0):

My answer includes [Arthurdent510's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2655876/1757576) but I don't have enough reputation to simply comment on his answer haha.    His answer helped me A LOT to figure out where I had to go, but it wasn't quite complete for me.

Putting the Response.Redirect call in the EndRequest handler caused an infinite loop.  I think this is because the Response.Redirect causes EndRequest to be called.  So EndRequest was being called over and over forever.

To get around this, I added a private boolean to indicate if I already called for the redirect.  If I already called for the redirect, then I won't call Response.Redirect again.  This is what my EndRequest method looked like:

```
Private Sub Application_EndRequest(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Not _blnHasAccess AndAlso Not _blnRedirected Then
        _blnRedirected = True
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx")
    End If
End Sub
```