# Access to session variables from IHttpModule's OnBeginRequest method

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables, ihttpmodule

I have a website that, in order to work properly, needs to have a XML file appended to all its URLs, let's say the file is called `module-1.xml`.

In order to keep those URls clean, I wrote a  IHttpModule's that uses the `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath` to do the appending job inside the `OnBeginRequest` event.

The IHttpModule looks pretty simple and works:

```
public void OnBeginRequest(Object s, EventArgs e)
{
   string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
   if (url.EndsWith(".aspx"))
      HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(url + "?module-1.xml");
}
```

Now, I wanted to use the session variable to detect when a user decides to switch the website from `model-1.xml` to `model-2.xml` and have my code changed as follow:

```
public void OnBeginRequest(Object s, EventArgs e)
{
   string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
   if (url.EndsWith(".aspx"))
   {
      if (HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentMode"] == "1")
         HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(url + "?module-1.xml");
      else if(HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentMode"] == "2")
         HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(url + "?module-2.xml");
    }
}
```

[From what I have found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276355/can-i-access-session-state-from-an-httpmodule), the session can be accessed inside a module but 
not from inside the `OnBeginRequest` event which is the only event where `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath` can be made functional (at least from all the testing I have been doing).

Is my assumption correct? And if it is, what alternative could I use? Create a custom Session variable? Should I read from a txt file or from a DB in order to know what module the user is looking at? How could I keep track of a user from within the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the security required by your application.  If you don't care about a malicious user being able to change the value, just store the module name in a cookie.  If you do, you could store a securely generated identifier in a cookie, and look that up in a database to get the value you need to use.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the module completely. You are only attaching it to aspx pages, so there is no need for that to be in the URL. Instead just create a base page for your project pages to inherit from:

```
public class Solution.Web.UI.Page : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string CurrentMode 
    { 
        get { return String.Compare(Session["CurrentMod"].ToString(), "1") == 0) ? "module-1.xml" : "module-2.xml"; }
    }
}
```

That way you can simply access it on your pages without the overhead of that module or the risk of putting that info in a cookie.

Comment: Thanks, but I still need to append the xml file to all the aspx files depending on the value located inside the session...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does appending it to the URL do?

Comment: We have got controls on all the pages that connect to an OPC server and display real-time data. Unfortunately, the only way to make all these controls work is by handing over a XML file through the URL. It's a pain but there is no way around it, it's third party product agreement from our company and we have to live it... for now :)