# Setting session variable in class that implements IHttpModule error

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, ihttpmodule

I am trying to set a session variable in a class that implements IHttpModule. I receive a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Here is my code:

```
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += context_PreRequestHandlerExecute;

    }

    private void context_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication) sender;
        HttpRequest request = app.Context.Request;
        app.Session.Add("capath", request.QueryString["capath"].ToString());


    }
```

Please help.

Comment: is the following not null? request.QueryString["capath"]

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276355/can-i-access-session-state-from-an-httpmodule

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso omw, cannot believe i missed that all this time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the issue is that the query string does not contain "capath" key / value and you get the object null exception because you call `.ToString()` on a null object