# 'session state not available in this context' in IHttpModule AJAX Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mvp, csrf

I know this is a somewhat common issue but, I've yet to find a solution so, any and all help or comments really appreciated.

In a IHttpModule implementation, in the Init method I've setup a handler as so:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
  context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(PreRequestHandlerExecute);
}
```

In the PreRequestHandlerExecute method, for any AJAX calls, I get a 'session state not available in this context' exception.

```
public void PostRequestHandlerExecute(Object application, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = application as HttpApplication;
        var a = app.Session["csrf_token"];
```

Alternatively, doing this results in an NullReferenceException

```
var b = HttpContext.Current.Session["csrf_token"];
```

I'm trying to access an object in the Session, the object is put there and read there during non-ajax calls without any issues.

Question(s) specifically is:
Is there an alternative location I can or should store the object in rather than the Session (other than a DB or Cookie)?

--Or--

Is there a way to make the Session available during an AJAX request, via some configuration or something maybe?

--Or--

Am I just doing something I shouldn't in .Net in general. I'm a native Java person, .Net concepts are new to me.

(Trying to implement the 'Synchronizer Token Pattern' to prevent CSRF in an aspx MVP application  if that helps)

Thanks Very Much
John

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I access session state from an HTTPModule?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276355/can-i-access-session-state-from-an-httpmodule)

Comment: May be this will help:
[HttpModule, Session state and WebResource.axd](http://forums.asp.net/p/930979/1122417.aspx)

Comment: @Andrei This resource: http://forums.asp.net/p/1098574/1665773.aspx is the one that solved the issue for me, it provides slightly more clarity than the SO answers. I think your link comes from that. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, another solution for the purposes of CSRF protection could be to use Runtime.cache instead of the Session. The cache key can incorporate an id uniquely identifying the user e.g. the username. The timeout for the cache should probably exceed the session or authentication timeout time in order to avoid it timing out ahead of the session expiration. The caching should be applied so that accessing it renews the cache expiration time. I.e. sliding expiration as opposed to absolute expiration. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.add(v=vs.110).aspx

```
if( HttpRuntime.Cache.Get("dummy") == null )
{
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Add("dummy", "==Username + CSRF TOKEN", null,
                        DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)),                 Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                                 CacheItemPriority.Normal,
                                 null);
 } else
 {
     var a = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get("dummy");
     Debug.WriteLine(a);
 }
```

Runtime.Cache is always available. That way the CSRF token received in the ajax or non-ajax request can be compared to the cache value rather than a session value.