# How to handle Session in IHttpModule?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please see below code

```
public class URLRewriter : IHttpModule {

    public void Dispose() {

    }
    public void Init( HttpApplication context ) {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler( context_BeginRequest );
    }

    void context_BeginRequest( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
                //code to make custom 
                 URLhttpApplication.Context.Server.Transfer( CustomPath );

        }
}
```

Here i am using `IHttpModule` for making custom URL redirection. But it showing error while setting session in destination page.

ERROR LINE Code :

`HttpContext.Current.Session[USERADMIN] == null`

ERROR Message:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

Comment: Check this other post:
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276355/can-i-access-session-state-from-an-httpmodule

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for Session state in `BeginRequest`, which is before the session state is available in the application's lifecycle. At minimum, you can't use session state until the [AcquireRequestState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.acquirerequeststate.aspx) event.

Change your `Init` to handle the AcquireRequestState instead of BeginRequest.